# What is the time complexity of the recurrence T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 4

Tags: recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the recurrence T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 4 ?

I'm having serious problems with this. 
I tried:

T(n) = 2T(n-1)+4  = 2(2T(n-2)+4)+4 = 4T(n-2)+12= 4(2T(n-3)+4)+4 = 8T(n-3)+20 = 8(2T(n-4)+4)+4 =
 16T(n-4)+36 =…

T(n) = 2^kT(n-k) + (4+2^(k+1))

so it looks like T(n) = 2^n + (4+2^(n+1)) but it doesn't seem right... please help :(

Comment: You didn't tell us the initialization. Is it `T(0) = 0` or `T(0) = 1` ? Or you don't care and you only want the `O` asymptotic ?

Comment: O(n) it is polynomial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation are wrong. I'm assuming here that `T(0)=0`

```
T(n) =                       2T(n-1)+  4 
     =   2(2T(n-2)+4)+  4 =  4T(n-2)+ 12
     =   4(2T(n-3)+4)+ 12 =  8T(n-3)+ 28 
     =   8(2T(n-4)+4)+ 28 = 16T(n-4)+ 60
     =  16(2T(n-5)+4)+ 60 = 32T(n-5)+124
     =  32(2T(n-6)+4)+124 = 64T(n-6)+252
```

Then now: look at the sequence

```
0,4,12,28,60,124,252,508,1020,2044,...
```

It is very tempting to add 4 to all these numbers:

```
4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,...
```

Do you recognize it ? So the guess is clearly

```
T(n) = 2^(n+2) - 4
```

Now, you can easily prove it by induction.

By the way if `T(0)` is not equal to `0` the formula is

```
T(n) = 2^(n+2) - 4 + T(0)*2^n
```

Comment: Always find the base case for recurrence problems. Base case will help to derive the whole formula. In this case, base case is T(0)

Answer (score 3):

Solving the recurrence relation, I found this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1
```

Let `n = log m` then, we get `T(log m)=2T(log m - log 2) + 1`

Assume `S(a) = 2S(a/2) + 1`

Applying Master's theorem we get:
       `n^logb^a = n^log2^2 = n`.

`n^log2^2-1 = 1`, here `€ = 1`

By first case we get: `S(a) = O(a)`

therefore `T(n) = O(2^n)`