# What is the recurrence relation and big O for T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(N)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I thought it would be something like this...

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(n)

     = 2(2T(n-2)+(n-1)) + (n)
     = 2(2(2T(n-3)+(n-2))+(n-1))+(n)
     = 8T(n-3) + 4(n-2) + 2(n-1) + n
```

Which ends up being something like the summation of 2<sup>i</sup> * (n-i), and my book says this ends up being O(2<sup>n</sup>). Could anybody explain this to me? I don't understand why it's 2<sup>n</sup> and not just O(n) as the (n-i) will continue n times.

Comment: Which book says this (I don't understand this either, but maybe more context will help)?

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong sub-expression. `2^i` is the dominant part.

Comment: So if 2^i is dominant, does that mean that the recurrence of T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1 is the same?

Comment: @hendersawn: Yes, you got it correct actually. The dominant part is generated from the coefficient of T(n - 1) in the recurrence. Therefore as long as the constant and other parts in the recurrence are not comparable or greater than T(n - 1), the recurrence will yield the same run-time.

Answer (score 1):

This recurrence has already been solved on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239974/solve-the-recurrence-tn-2tn-1-n). As I solve this recurrence, I get:

```
T(n) = n + 2(T(n-1))
     = n + 2(n - 1 + 2T(n-2))            = 3n - 2 + 2^2(T(n-2))
     = 3n - 2 + 4(n - 2 + 2(T(n-3)))     = 7n - 10 + 2^3(T(n-3))
     = 7n - 10 + 8(n - 3 + 2(T(n-4)))    = 15n - 34 + 2^4(T(n-4))
                                         = (2^4 - 1)n - 34 + 2^4(T(n-4))
```

...and so on.

Effectively the recurrence boils down to:

> T(n) = (2<sup>n+1</sup>) * T(1) − n − 2

See the Math Stack Exchange link for how we arrive at this solution. Taking T(1) to be constant, the dominating factor in the above recurrence is **(2<sup>(n + 1)</sup>)**.

Therefore, the rate of growth of given recurrence is **O(2<sup>n</sup>)**.

Comment: So I'm having trouble understanding - if the recurrence was 2T(n-1) + 1 instead of 2T(n-1) + n, would it still be 2^n?

Comment: @hendersawn: Yes, it will still be O(2^n). A similar recurrence has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741590/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-recurrence-tn-2tn-1-4